# How to call a complex SQL query in python

Tags: python, sql

I have the following SQL code:

```
select * from dbo.dictionary;
select d1.literal_id, d1.text as spanish , d2.text as english,d1.id as 'id(spanish)',d2.id as 'id(english)' from dictionary d1
left join dictionary d2
on d1.literal_id = d2.literal_id
and d2.lenguaje =223622
where d1.lenguaje =223621;
```

This SQL code has been tested and runs perfectly on SQL Server Management Studio.

Now I have the following code for python which is to communicate with an MS SQL Server instance:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

server = 'my-server-name'
database = 'my_db_name'
username = 'MYUSERNAME'
password = 'MYPASSWORD'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from dbo.dictionary;
select d1.literal_id, d1.text as spanish , d2.text as english,d1.id as 'id(spanish)',d2.id as 'id(english)' from dictionary d1
left join dictionary d2
on d1.literal_id = d2.literal_id
and d2.lenguaje =223622
where d1.lenguaje =223621;', cnxn)

print(df)
```

When I run it, I get the following error

```
EOL while scanning string literal
```

where it points to the first semicolon in my code. Could you show me how I may get this python code to run?

Comment: first for multiline text you need to use ''' not '. second you appear to actually be running two queries in your sql (there are two selects) and I do not believe pyodbc supports such, certainly pandas has no idea how to handle cramming two tables into one table. the use of the semicolon is also unnecessary for a single query.

Comment: I'm wondering what you are expecting here.  Your two SELECT statements have different columns.  How do you expect pandas to straighten it out?  I suspect you just need to remove the first SELECT completely, and use triple-quotes for multi-line literals, as @born_naked pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing the quotes and removing the select statement, and I'm pretty sure the last two lines of your SQL got swapped.  It should be WHERE...AND, not AND...WHERE.  Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

server = 'my-server-name'
database = 'my_db_name'
username = 'MYUSERNAME'
password = 'MYPASSWORD'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

df = pd.read_sql_query("""
SELECT d1.literal_id, d1.text as spanish, d2.text as english,
       d1.id as 'id(spanish)',d2.id as 'id(english)'
FROM dictionary d1
   LEFT JOIN dictionary d2
      ON d1.literal_id = d2.literal_id
WHERE d1.lenguaje = 223621
      AND d2.lenguaje = 223622;""", cnxn)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Roberts! It worked! Happy New Year!